# OLEDB AccessViolationException when Reconnecting to Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, vb.net, oledb, access-violation, uipath

Am currently using UiPath (Visual Basic) to automate processes.
One portion of the process uses large excel files, so I'm interacting with them using OLEDB and SQL.

Have had no problem testing on my individual VDI, however when deploying on an Azure VM, I've been having issues with the OLEDB connection.

Connecting to an Excel workbook with OLEDB works the first time around, but after disconnecting and disposing, if I try to reconnect to the same Excel workbook I get AccessViolationExceptions.

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper.InitializeAndCreateSession(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString, System.Data.OleDb.SessionWrapper ByRef)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString, System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, System.Object, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, System.Object, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolGroup, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at UiPath.Database.DatabaseConnection.OpenConnection()
   at UiPath.Database.DatabaseConnection..ctor(System.String, System.String)
   at UiPath.Database.Activities.DatabaseConnect+<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<BeginExecute>b__0()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr, System.Object[], System.Object, System.Object[] ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessageSink)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

I've tried editing my connection string to disable pooling to no avail. Has anyone else run into similar issues? Could it be due to the multiple users in the Azure environment? My VDI has multiple users however. Am stumped on this one.

VDI was running Win 7 Professional with Office 2010

Azure VM is running Win 10 with Office 2016

My connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= {0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Readonly=False;IMEX=1';
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Hmm, I am running in the same problem (which is new behaviour). Did you ever got this solved?

Answer (score -1):

this error is about windows system architecture, system 32 and 64. When the system creates a OleDb instance, he call MSCorlib, thats located at diferent directories, x(86) and so.